# Is it safe to "initialize" an object of type T with *this = T() in a constructor of T?

Tags: c++

Is the constructor Year() safe in this case ?

```
struct Year {
   int year;
   Year(int y) : year(y) {}
   Year() { *this = Year(1970); } // *this = this->operator=(Year(1970));
};

Year y;
```

I think yes, because year has already been initialized with int() once the execution flows reaches the constructor body. Are there other problems to consider?

Don't consider other cases in which the same trick might cause troubles.

Comment: Sure in this very trivial case. Would not want to though (other problems could arise in more complex situations).

Answer (score 5):

Sure, [this will work](http://codepad.org/gtSjCx8c), and is valid.

---

#### Explanation

All data members and bases have already been constructed by the time your ctor-body runs, and:

> `[n3290: 12.7/4]` **Member functions**, including virtual functions
>   (10.3), **can be called during construction or destruction** (12.6.2). [..]

Not to be confused with:

> `[n3290: 12.7/1]` For an object with a non-trivial constructor, **referring to any
>   non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor
>   begins execution results in undefined behavior**.

(NB. "before the constructor begins"; this clause does not apply here.)

And there's nothing in `12.8 "Copying and moving class objects"` to prohibit assignment during construction.

---

#### Caveat

Note that this does *not* mean that the object has begun its "lifetime":

> `[n3290: 3.8/1]:` The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete.

And the final step in "initialization" for a non-delegating ctor:

> `[n3290: 12.6.2/10]:` [..] Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed.

Put altogether, this means that an object's "lifetime" doesn't begin until its most derived constructor body has finished executing.

In particular, passing a pointer to the object before it has started its life is not very useful, as doing almost anything through that pointer invokes Undefined Behaviour:

> `[n3290: 3.5/8]:` Before the lifetime of an object has started but
>   after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated
>   or, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage
>   which the object occupied is reused or released, any pointer that
>   refers to the storage location where the object will be or was located
>   may be used but only in limited ways. [..]

However:

> `[n3290: 3.8/3]:` [..] [ Note: [..] Also, the behavior of an object
>   under construction and destruction might not be the same as the
>   behavior of an object whose lifetime has started and not ended. 12.6.2
>   and 12.7 describe the behavior of objects during the construction and
>   destruction phases. —end note ]

And, as we've already explored, `12.7` kindly informs us that members *may* be accessed during this phase of construction.

---

#### Suggestion

Your approach is hard to follow, though; I also had to look up the above passage before I could be sure that it's valid, so it's clearly not entirely intuitive.

Fortunately C++0x introduces constructor delegation, so that you can write:

```
struct Year {
   Year()      : Year(1970) {}
   Year(int y) : year(y)    {}

   int year;
};
```

<sup>(Alas, GCC 4.5.1 doesn't support this, so [I cannot demonstrate it to you on ideone.com](http://www.ideone.com/fv8Ns). In fact, [for GCC as a whole there's only a "partial patch" at time of writing](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).)</sup>

Comment: Well, indeed, the OP's problem can certainly be avoided by proper class design :-)

Comment: Doesn't the first quote only applies to types, not to instances?

Comment: Also, my phrasing about an object's lifetime beginning when the constructor has completed comes directly from Scott Meyer's book, so I have a certain amount of confidence in it, although I have not verified this in the standard. Maybe now is the time :-)

Comment: @Kerrek: True; that quote wasn't relevant actually. The new first one is though!

Comment: @Kerrek: 3.8/1 says: "The lifetime of an object of type T begins when: — storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and — if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete." If Meyer really says otherwise, then he's wrong.

Comment: 12.6.2/10 does confound this slightly, by saying that the final step in "initialization" (for a non-delegating ctor) is: "Finally, the compound-statement of the constructor body is executed." But this doesn't entirely line up with terminology used elsewhere.

Comment: I see, seems right. I mean, you couldn't call an *foreign* function `f(*this)` in the constructor, but member functions make sense. (Meyers *does* warn against calling *virtual* functions in a constructor, though, because they usually don't do what you think. Otherwise his reasoning doesn't apply here, so the blame is entirely on me.)

Comment: @Kerrek: I actually don't believe that that's true about foreign calls. And all members will be constructed by this point so it's certainly "safe". But yea, playing with `virtual` function members gets messy; 12.7 covers all that.

Comment: If this is indeed correct - and the quotes seem to indicate this, then what about [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html) post - point 10.3 (placement new). Maybe I'm missing some detail, but why is the one allowed and the other not? (and I think the author in general has some idea about what he's talking - him being part of the c++ standardization comitee and so)

Comment: @Voo: Objects that are allocated via placement `new` are suppose to be explicitly destructed by having their destructor called ... so  this could create a lot of havoc, especially if you are allocating the object on the heap or creating it by a call to `new`.  The end-user won't know about the placement `new` call, and will simply call `delete` on the pointer, which would be non-standard behavior.

Comment: @Jason But those problems can be circumvented and actually the FAQ is talking about that quite a lot in a different place. That's something different than categorically saying that the placement new solution is broken as he does.

Comment: @Voo: That's an entirely different example. He's not using his newly-constructor temporary; we are. And his warning is about trying to use placement `new` to "overwrite" the object currently under construction, which is undefined I think: what happens when the original member variables go out of scope?

Comment: Sure it can work if you are careful. But that does not mean it is a good idea or even safe in all situations. The members may be initialized but some members default initialization can be to do nothing. As a result the object is not really considered fully constructed until the constructor ends. Thus you are assigning a fully constructed object onto a partially constructed object. This technically may not be illegal but it is definitely not good practice.

Comment: @Martin: I don't see how it can ever be unsafe unless your object is inherently unsafe anyway. If a member's default initialization is to "to nothing", then nothing that occurs in the ctor body is going to change that. Of course I'm also not suggesting this as a pattern to use; as I said, it can be hard to follow the logic of it.

Comment: @Tomalak: If you have a pointer member. After the initializer-list (unless you explicitly set it) it has a random value. Thus it is not initialized. You may initialize it during the constructor body because of some complex logic that makes it hard to do in the initializer list. If you happen to use this assignment above before you set the pointer then things might start to go wonky (things can move during maintance). The problem with the above code is you have to make sure you use it correctly the compiler will not check. Thus it is not good practice, because it is too easy to make a mistake.

Comment: @Tomalak: Any maintainer that modifies the assignment operator must also know that it is being abused in the constructor to make sure any modifications to the assignment operator will not break the constructor. This makes the code inherently brittle and subject to bugs. in the long term. This is bad design. Thus it is bad practice.

Comment: So sure it will work in this simple easy to verify situation. But any class that has even a slightly more complex nature becomes a maintenance nightmare. And no self respecting senior engineer would let you check it into source control.

Comment: I'm tempted to agree with Martin. I think about it like this: From a pure "valid memory" perspective, Tomalak's quote applies and you can access members and call member functions. But *semantically* the object may well not be in a coherent state until the constructor has finished. The resolution of this paradox is that it is up to the class designer to know her class well enough to guarantee that member function use (including assignment) in the constructor maintains the class invariants. It's OK as far as the compiler is concerned, but the higher-level correctness is up to the author.

Comment: Guys, again, I never claimed that it's good practice. It's not. My answer even says that, and has from the very first revision. I merely dispute your theory that it's in any way _inherently_ **unsafe**. The standard guarantees that the assignment _itself_ is safe; that's it. (And your `operator=` should _never_ need to care about the context in which the assignment is taking place; I don't see why that would suddenly become the case here.)

Comment: I have updated my answer to clarify the meaning of "object lifetime".

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal While informing myself a bit about c++0x I stumbled upon [this](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#delegating-ctor) which is pretty much exactly about this topic. Now the question is: If the above was already allowed in the C++98 standard why specify the new syntax (and change several paragraphs in the standard?)? Also see [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1986) paper. Anyways as soon as all compilers implement the new syntax that's surely the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing works, but what wouldn't work would be if you somehow recursively called a constructor ... that would cause problems.  But since the constructor is called after all non-static data-members of the object have been constructed, and the `this` pointer is pointing to valid memory that can be copied into, what you've done is okay--it's not standard practice, but it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is probably wrong; see Tomalak's answer and the comments. I'll leave it for historic reasons, but you're probably OK calling member functions during the constructor.*

Most definitely not. If you have any `T*`, say `p`, then you may only invoke member functions via `p->` if `p` points to an object. But an object only begins its life when its constructor has finished. So while you're in the middle of the constructor, `this` does not point to an object! Therefore, you can most certainly not invoke any member functions like the assignment operator on this not-yet object.

[Curiosum: It *is* legit to say `delete this;` in certain situations, you just have to make sure that the destructor does not refer to `this` in any way. It is also OK to pass `this` to some other place during the constructor, as long as it is not *dereferenced*, much like you can pass any garbage pointer around as long as you don't use it.]

Comment: Hmm, I'm not entirely sure about this. You can obviously access data members in the ctor body, and I've never had trouble with function members.

Comment: Actually that doesn't quite make sense because before the constructor body is entered, all non-static data-members have already been initialized, either by default initialization, or they are in an indeterminate state.  The `this` pointer then points to memory that has already been allocated, and the constructor is basically being called after all the sub-objects have been created and allocated in the same memory-structure that the `this` is pointing to.  So `this` does point to an object.

Comment: @Jason: Just because `this` points to some allocated memory that is very soon going to hold an object does not contradict the fact that an object's lifetime begins when (one of) its constructors completes. Naturally, subobjects and base objects come to life before the containing object.

Comment: My answer includes [final draft] standard quotes that I believe contradict this answer. You're right that, _in most contexts_, the object is not a _completely-defined object_ until the closing `}` of the selected ctor body... but this is not one of those contexts. :)

Comment: @Kerrek SB : Constructors are like `init` functions in C with the the struct memory being "constructed" being passed in as the `this` pointer rather than the explicit methods that have to be employed with C `init` functions.  Furthermore the constructor has a valid stack frame that temporary objects can be created on.  Therefore it's perfectly valid to create an object in the constructor's stack frame, and copy that object into the memory that is being pointed to by the `this` pointer.  He's not recursively calling any constructors, so he's okay.

Comment: @Jason: Those are implementation details. ("There is no stack.") I'm arguing purely from within the language here, which defines object lifetimes. Practically, you could contrive constructors which perform various bits of data mangling so that the to-be object really wouldn't be in a consistent state until the constructor finishes.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : "There is no stack"?? ... there must be a stack-frame for the constructor, or how else could you throw an exception inside a constructor, and then catch it?

Comment: @Jason: That's implementation-defined. The language does not prescribe a stack-based architecture.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : Okay, I see what you mean ... I think Tomalak's quotes from the standard pretty much answer the question though ...

Comment: I haven't the heart to downvote this. Creds for leaving it up!

Comment: I updated my answer, having finally worked out where object lifetime comes into all this. You were on the money about object lifetime, but there are caveats that make this work anyway.

Comment: @Tomalak: Cool, that's a comprehensive answer now. Very nice.